# Tomcat's context hierarchy

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I know tomcat can define *Contexts* in a few different ways. For this particular question, I have a main context defined in *$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml*, and per module context's defined in each respective module's */META-INF/context.xml*. My question is, if I have set certain parameters in the main context that aren't been set/overrided in the per module contexts, will those parameters still take effect when loading the per module contexts.

Example:

```
|----$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml (i have logAbandoned=true set here)
|
|----webaps
       |
       |---META-INF/context.xml (no mention of logAbandoned here)
```

In the above scenario, will `logAbandoned=true` apply to the webapp's context since it hasn't been overwritten or included? Or will only the parameters set in *META-INF/context.xml* be applied without applying any parameters set in the main *context.xml*.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Apache's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context):

> Default Context elements may be defined that apply to multiple web
>   applications. Configuration for an individual web application will
>   override anything configured in one of these defaults. Any nested
>   elements, e.g.  elements, that are defined in a default
>   Context will be created once for each Context to which the default
>   applies. They will not be shared between Context elements.
>
> - In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml file: the Context element information will be loaded by all web applications.
> - In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default file:
>     the Context element information will be loaded by all web applications
>     of that host.

So it looks like the main context is applied first for all applications, and then the module's context is applied, overriding any context elements that match from the default context.xml.

Comment: +1. Just wanted to post a similar answer but you were first )